# (MVVM-light) style.triggers dont works

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, datatrigger, attached-properties

I'm doing `WPF(MVVM)` project using `mvvm-light` libraries, and have such problem: I want to create style trigger dependent on value from my ModelView, but it's do not works

`XAML` Part :

```
<Window...

<Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Declaratively create an instance of our Alarm View Model-->
        <local:AlarmView />
</Window.DataContext>
....

<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ChangeLocation}" Content="Click"></Button>    
<ListView 
         Grid.Row="1"
         Name="LV1" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         >
<ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Location}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Location}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Location}" Value="2">
                        <Setter  Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Location}" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>    
 </ListView>
 </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Part from `ModelView`:

```
class AlarmView : ViewModelBase
{
...
int _location = 0;
...
public int Location 
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set 
        {
            _location = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }    
...
public RelayCommand ChangeLocation { get; set; }
...
ChangeLocation = new RelayCommand(() => 
        {
            if (Location < 3)
            {
                Location++;
            }
            else Location = 0;
        });
...
```

It seems to be ok, but when I change Location nothing happens. To check  my command, I bind it to `TextBox` - all works. 
Where can be problem?

Comment: Did you try two-way binding (I'm not sure if this is the default).  `{Binding Path=Location,Mode=TwoWay}`

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the output window in VS during runtime? By the way I've copied your exact code to an empty mvvmlight project and it works fine. When I clicking on the button the colspan of the listview changes accordingly. So something is wrong in the other parts of your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your binding? I had a similar problem and that fixed it for me.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
     <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```